How to find the representing matrix of a quadratic form with respect to a non-standard basis?
Given the quadratic form $( q(x, y, z) = x^2 + 2xy + 6xz + 4yz + z^2 )$, I know how to find the representing matrix for the standard basis. The representing matrix for the standard basis is:
$$
Q = \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1 & 3 \\
1 & 0 & 2 \\
3 & 2 & 1
\end{pmatrix}
$$
How can I find the representing matrix for a given basis such as $(\{(1,0,0), (0,1,0), (1,1,1)\})$?

You ask how ... but don’t you merely need to perform a change of basis?

I assume you're talking about quadratic forms over real vector spaces.
Write $q(v)$ for the evaluation of $q$ on a vector $v$. Every quadratic form has an associated bilinear form
$$
  B(v,w) = \frac12(q(v+w) - q(v) - q(w))
$$
where $v,w$ are vectors. The matrix $Q_E$ of $q$ in an arbitrary basis $E=(e_1,\dotsc,e_n)$ is an arbitrary basis is just the matrix of $B$, i.e.
$$
  (Q_E)_{ij} = B(e_i,e_j).
$$
For $v,w$ expressed in the $E$-basis we can write
$$
  B(v,w) = v^TQ_Ew,\quad q(v) = B(v,v) = v^TQ_Ev.
$$

You could apply a change-of-basis to the standard matrix $Q$, but you need to be careful. Let $M$ be the usual change-of-basis matrix from $E$ to the standard basis (i.e. $M_{ij} = (e_j)_i$ for $e_j$ expressed in the standard basis). Then for $v,w$ in the $E$ basis
$$
  v^TQ_Ew = B(v,w) = (Mv)^TQ(Mw) = v^T(M^TQM)w
$$
so $Q_E = M^TQM$.
This is not the same as how a linear transformation matrix transforms. If a matrix $A$ represents a linear transformation then we know it transforms as
$$
  A \mapsto M^{-1}AM.
$$
But we just showed that bilinear/quadratic form matrices $Q$ transform as
$$
  Q \mapsto M^TQM.
$$
They are not the same!
